# Doctrine 2 Command line print Cygwin configuration

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I am trying to use Doctrine 2 in my project, but when I try to access the command line to import the Entities from my database to generate the files, it print the code from `vendor/bin/doctrine`

```
dir=$(d=${0%[/\\]*}; cd "$d"; cd '../doctrine/orm/bin' && pwd)

# See if we are running in Cygwin by checking for cygpath program
if command -v 'cygpath' >/dev/null 2>&1; then
    # Cygwin paths start with /cygdrive/ which will break windows PHP,
    # so we need to translate the dir path to windows format. However
    # we could be using cygwin PHP which does not require this, so we
    # test if the path to PHP starts with /cygdrive/ rather than /usr/bin
    if [[ $(which php) == /cygdrive/* ]]; then
            dir=$(cygpath -m $dir);
    fi
fi

dir=$(echo $dir | sed 's/ /\ /g')
"${dir}/doctrine.php" "$@"
```

My folder structure:

```
src/
vendor/
bootstrap.php
cli-config.php
composer.json
composer.lock
index.php
```

bootstrap.php

```
<?php

require_once "vendor/autoload.php";

use Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Setup;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;

$paths = array("src/Entity");
$isDevMode = false;

// the connection configuration
$dbParams = array(
    'driver'   => 'pdo_mysql',
    'user'     => '',
    'password' => '',
    'dbname'   => '',
);

$config = Setup::createAnnotationMetadataConfiguration($paths, $isDevMode);
$entityManager = EntityManager::create($dbParams, $config);
```

cli-config.php

```
<?php

use Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Console\ConsoleRunner;

// replace with file to your own project bootstrap
require_once 'bootstrap.php';

// replace with mechanism to retrieve EntityManager in your app
$entityManager = GetEntityManager();

return ConsoleRunner::createHelperSet($entityManager);
```

I am trying to use in my command line: `php vendor/bin/doctrine --help`. I am using also Vagrant with Ubuntu 14.01.

I am not using Symfony 2, Just trying to install Doctrine without any framework.

Thank you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I got the same error when I was in windows setup and this command worked to resolve it:

```
php vendor/doctrine/orm/bin/doctrine.php orm:schema-tool:create
```

**Source:**
http://www.agevaled.com/2013/10/09/doctrine2-getting-started-issues/2147483647/

Answer (score -1):

On Windows, the correct command to run is:

`vendor/bin/doctrine.bat`

Comment: .bat is a script file that requires cmd.exe which is available only in windows. Details are in the link below.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45804719/how-to-run-pass-docker-terminal-commands-using-bat-file