# We are in Cgywin using Windows php, so the path must be translated warning in windows 10

Tags: windows-10, laravel-blade, java-platform-module-system, cmder

I tried to follow this tutorial 
https://gist.github.com/dfontana/3e27ec5ea3a6f935b7322b580d3df318.

but I got lost in the steps now I'm experiencing this error in windows 10 while trying to run jigsaw a static site generator using blade syntax in a  windows 10 pc

````
D:\www\jigsaw-projects\test-site
λ php .\vendor\bin\jigsaw

dir=$(cd "${0%[/\\]*}" > /dev/null; cd "../tightenco/jigsaw" && pwd)

if [ -d /proc/cygdrive ] && [[ $(which php) == $(readlink -n /proc/cygdrive)/* ]]; then
   # We are in Cgywin using Windows php, so the path must be translated
   dir=$(cygpath -m "$dir");
fi

"${dir}/jigsaw" "$@"```
````

This is the full error.  Anything I can ask for help  ?

Comment: Maybe you have a php executable somewhere inside the jigsaw bin? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33416661/doctrine-2-command-line-print-cygwin-configuration